# How can I make Option B work properly because last answer did not quite work

Tags: python-3.x

I need it so if you pick Option B you can input a number and it will tell you if it is a floating-point number. Kinda like how if you pick Option A and you input a number it will let you input a number and tell you if it is an integer.

This is my Code:

```
def getNumber():
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input("What number would like to test as an integer ? "))
            return userInput
        except ValueError as ve:
            print("Not an integer! Try again.")
            continue

print("What would you like to do?")
print("Option A = Interger")
print("Option B = Floating Point")
Msg = input()
if Msg == 'A':
    integer_received = getNumber()
    print(integer_received, "is an int !")
else:
    print("You did not choose 'A' or 'B', make sure it is capitalized!")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def getNumber():
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input("What number would like to test as an integer ? "))
            return userInput
        except ValueError as ve:
            print("Not an integer! Try again.")
            continue

def getFloatintNumber():
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = float(input("What number would like to test as float ? "))
            return userInput
        except ValueError as ve:
            print("Not a float! Try again.")
            continue


print("What would you like to do?")
print("Option A = Interger")
print("Option B = Floating Point")
Msg = input()
if Msg == 'A':
    integer_received = getNumber()
    print(integer_received, "is an int !")
elif Msg == 'B':
    float_received = getFloatintNumber()
    print(float_received, "is a float !")
else:
    print("You did not choose 'A' or 'B', make sure it is capitalized!")
```